# Primefaces DialogFramework Growl and showMessageInDialog not working

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I am using `primefaces dialogFramework`. I have a `Table.xhtml` file as follows

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
    <p:dataTable id="colors" var="col" value="#{tableDialog.resourceList}" rowKey="#{col}"  
                 selection="#{tableDialog.selected}" selectionMode="single">  
        <p:column headerText="Model">#{col}</p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>  
    <p:contextMenu for="colors">
        <p:menuitem  value="Add"  onclick="triggerHiddenEvent(); return false;" update=":form:colors" />
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:commandButton id="hiddenCommand" styleClass="button"  action="#{tableDialog.updateValue}"  style="display:none">
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn"  update = ":form:colors :form:growl " action="#{tableDialog.showValue}" actionListener="#{tableDialog.showValue}"  />  
    </p:commandButton>

    <h:outputScript >
        function triggerHiddenEvent() {
        document.getElementById("form:hiddenCommand").click();
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

and the corresponding `ManagedBean`is as follows

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableDialog {

    public ArrayList<String> resourceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String selected;

    String attributeValue = null;

    public TableDialog() {
        this.resourceList.add("Black");
        this.resourceList.add("White");

    }

    public void updateValue() {
        System.out.println("update  value");
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("resizable", false);
        options.put("dynamic", true);
        options.put("height", 100);
        options.put("width", 300);
        options.put("contentHeight", 100);
        options.put("contentWidth", 250);
        context.openDialog("Dialog", options, null);
    }

    public void cancelValue() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.closeDialog(this.attributeValue);
        System.out.println("cancel update resource attribute value");
        this.attributeValue = null;
        System.out.println("this.attributevalue  = " + this.attributeValue);

    }

    public void saveValue() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (this.attributeValue == null) {
            System.out.println("No value");
            context.execute("noValueDialog.show()");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("this.attributevalue = " + this.attributeValue);
        this.resourceList.add(this.attributeValue);
        context.update("form:resourceAttributeValueDataTable");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:resourceAttributeValueDataTable");
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Hello " + this.attributeValue));
        context.showMessageInDialog(new FacesMessage("Failure", "good bye " + this.attributeValue));
        this.attributeValue = null;
        context.closeDialog(this.attributeValue);
        System.out.println("after hidden button execute ");
    }

    public String getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(String selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getResourceList() {
        return resourceList;
    }

    public void setResourceList(ArrayList<String> resourceList) {
        this.resourceList = resourceList;
    }

    public String getAttributeValue() {
        return attributeValue;
    }

    public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

    public void showValue() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("successful", "hello " + this.attributeValue));
        System.out.println("showvalue from action ");
    }

    public void showValue(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("successful", "hello " + this.attributeValue));
        System.out.println("showvalue from actionlistener ");
    }
}
```

`Table.xhtml` opens `Dialog.xhtml` which is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Dialog</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>  
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  />

            <h:panelGrid id="updateValuePanel" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
                <h:outputLabel value="Attribute Value "  />
                <p:inputText id="attributeValue" value="#{tableDialog.attributeValue}" required="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>  

            <p:commandButton id="saveValue" value="Submit" actionListener="#{tableDialog.saveValue}"  update="growl" />
            <p:commandButton id="cancelValue" value="Cancel " action="#{tableDialog.cancelValue}"/>
            <p:defaultCommand target="saveValue" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**My Problem/Question:**

The `Dialog.xhtml` is used to add another value that will be shown on `Table.xhtml`. I want to use a `p:growl` or  `context.showMessageInDialog(....)` to show a message that the value is successfully added. For this I have the following possible options:

1. Update a growl on `Table.xhtml` after the `Dialog.xhtml` is closed using `context.closeDialog(this);`
2. Show a message using `context.showMessageInDialog(....)` after the `saveValue` `p:commandButton` is pressed but before the dialog is closed.
3. Update a growl pn Dialog.xhtml after the `saveValue` `p:commandButton` is pressed but before the dialog is closed.

I have tried all of the above but none of them appears. If I directly try to run `Dialog.xhtml` the p:growl on `Dialog.xhtml` and the `context.showMessageInDialog(....)` both appear easily.

Any help regarding how to display the above mentioned options while using DialogFramework will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to show a message using the growl component once the user clicks on the **saveValue** commandButton.

In this case I'd use a single growl outside the form on Table.xhtml.

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
```

**NOTE:** consider defining the autoUpdate attribute to true (**autoUpdate="true"**).

On your saveValue commandButton update like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveValue" value="Submit" actionListener="#{tableDialog.saveValue}"  update=":growl" />
```

This peace of code will be enough to add messages to your view:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Hello " + this.attributeValue));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the issue. Now the next point is that the growl gives null for the this.attributeValue on Table.xhtml. Can you please suggest some way to get the correct attributevalue in the growl?

Comment: I can't find the problem on that! Once you've defined the inputText as required, the actionListener will only be called if the this.attributeValue is not null (or empty). Are you getting something from that **System.out.println("this.attributevalue = " + this.attributeValue);**?

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been so helpful. It was my own silly mistake causing it to be null. In saveValue() I had this.attributeValue  = null; so that the next time the dialog opens the previous value is not present in the inputText. By removing that statement the correct value is displayed in the growl. Thanks again.